# tornado: missing ioloop.add_handler()

Tags: python, tornado

I miss ioloop.add_handler() in the example:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    http_server.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

From: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch3.1/web.html

The object http_server and ioloop are not explicitly connected. This looks not clean to me. How does ioloop discover the http_server?

Everything works fine, I am just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately http_server does connect to the IOLoop, as 
[HTTPServer](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch3.0/httpserver.html#tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer) is derived from [TCPServer](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch3.0/tcpserver.html). When you call its [listen()](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch3.0/tcpserver.html#tornado.tcpserver.TCPServer.listen) method, it in turn calls [tornado.netutil.add_accept_handler()](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch3.0/_modules/tornado/netutil.html#add_accept_handler) which calls ioloop.add_handler().

Comment: In the above example http_server.listen(8080) before the ioloop objects exists. I guess there are is some global variable magic. Everything works fine. It just looks strange to me. PS: I updated the example. Now copy+paste to a usable python-file works.

Comment: Look at IOLoop.instance() or IOLoop.current() to see how the IOLoop comes into existence. Source here: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch3.0/_modules/tornado/ioloop.html#IOLoop